# Config Server: native property source is ignored

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

This is my `bootstrap.yml` content file:

```
server.port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: configserver

  profiles:
    active: native, git, vault

  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: classpath:config/
          # searchLocations: file://${native_location}
          order: 3
        git:
          uri: file:///home/jcabre/projects/wsec-sccs/server/repo
          order: 2
        vault:
          host: ${vault_server_host:localhost}
          port: ${vault_server_port:8200}
          scheme: ${vault_server_scheme:https}
          backend: ${vault_backend:configserver}
          profileSeparator: /
          order: 1
```

As you can see I've stand up three backends: native, git, vault.

So `classpath:/config/application.yml` content:

```
foo: FROM NATIVE APPLICATION
```

`/home/jcabre/projects/wsec-sccs/server/repo/application.yml` content:

```
foo: FROM GIT
```

And Vault:

```
$ vault kv get configserver/configclient/                        
=== Data ===
Key    Value
---    -----
foo    FROM VAULT

$vault kv get configserver/configclient/dev
=== Data ===
Key    Value
---    -----
foo    FROM DEV VAULT
```

When I try to get `foo` config key using `curl`:

```
$ curl -sS -X GET http://localhost:8888/configclient/default -H "X-Config-Token: ${vault_token}" | jq .
{
  "name": "configclient",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": null,
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "vault:configclient",
      "source": {
        "foo": "FROM VAULT"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "file:///home/jcabre/projects/wsec-sccs/server/repo/application.yml",
      "source": {
        "foo": "FROM GIT APPLICATION"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I only get `git` and `vault` property sources, but it doesn't send me `native`.

How can this be happening?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got an answer to this, but I had a similar problem (no native profile when Vault was enabled) so I looked through the code (latest in GitHub).

It would appear that the NativeEnvironmentRepository is only enabled if the native profile is present AND no other environment repositories are configured. So it doesn't look like you are able to do what you want in the question.